# Why are only inactive plugins showing?

Tags: plugins

Pretty much sums it up. On the plugin page, only the inactive plugins show.

Comment: Should note that site functionality is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi-site install. Hitting "update network" twice fixed the problem. Go figure.

Comment: Any idea _why_ that worked?